# svn+ssh using Tortoise creates a separate ssh connection for each file -- any way to consolidate?

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn

My web hosting company has a "security feature" (not the purpose of this question!) which disallows many ssh connections in a short period of time from a single client IP address.  Unfortunately, that means TortoiseSVN can't use the svn+ssh scheme since it does just that:  a new connection for each file/directory being updated.

My question:  how can I work around this?

I currently have distributed ssh keys to two people and configured the web host's .ssh/authorized_keys so that they can only connect to svnserve on the web host.  This works from my Linux and OSX machines, but Tortoise tries too many times and the IP is blocked at that point.

Are there other Windows clients that handle this better?  Is there an ssh configuration (perhaps using tunneling) that will work?  (But be aware that tunneling is not directly supported by the web host, so I need to set up my own sshd_config and run a "private" sshd on a separate port and connect to that port from the client, so it's pretty ugly.)  Any other ideas that I'm missing?

Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: Looks like I'm able to move to Git instead.  Some initial testing to a server under my control shows that TortoiseGit only makes a single SSH connection to the Git server, so that _should_ solve my problem.  Bummer no one was able to answer this question though...